# Laravel delete or update doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a little problem...
So I have a code that gets all values from a table,

I want to delete or update the values of a table when the calumn 'expire' is smaller than the time() function.

I live in UTC +1 timezone, but okay...

I want to update in the first place the table 'deleted_at' to get all the data still in the database.

So how can I do this,

If I do an delete query:

```
$del = DB::table('event')->where('expire', '<', $time)->delete();
```

It doesn't work...

Please help me out (maybe by making an **UPDATE** query to update the deleted_at table to the current timestamp?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that `time()` returns the seconds that have past since 1970 and not a timestamp. (which I assume your db column is)

I suggest you use `Carbon` (the date library Laravel uses)

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$del = DB::table('event')->where('expired', '<', $now)->delete();
```

Or for soft delete:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$del = DB::table('event')->where('expired', '<', $now)->whereNull('deleted_at')->update(['deleted_at' => $now]);
```

Comment: It works, but my table keeps updating, so I want to add a parameter that says If the table deleted_at is still NULL, then they can update, otherwise not.... So now I have this: $del = DB::table('event')->where('expire', '<', $time)->update(['deleted_at' => $time]);

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to lukasgeiter I found the correct solution, this is the solution:

```
$del = DB::table('event')->where('expire', '<', $time)->where('deleted_at', 'IS NULL')->update(['deleted_at' => $time]);
```

The `$time` variable is the `time();` function, because I want to get the timestamp, not a date format.